# SQL Server 2008: How to compare XML?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, comparison

Is there are way to compare variables or columns of XML in SQL Server 2008, which is different from comparing a varchar that can be made from the XML value? Some hashing mechanisms?

For example:

```
declare @xml1 xml = '<Xml1/>'
declare @xml2 xml = '<Xml2/>'
select case when @xml1 = @xml2 then 1 else 0 end
```

Answer (score 12):

```
select case when cast(@xml1 as nvarchar(max)) = cast(@xml2 as nvarchar(max)) then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: I've just tried this out.  It works well.  Ignores differences in the whitespace, which is what I was worried about.  I compared two XML variables, set to identical XML apart from a couple of indents, and the comparison returned true.  However, after changing the text value of an element in one of them the comparison now returned false.

Comment: seems problem exists with white spaces